# How to add to div results of each step of recurtive function in JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, ecmascript-6, towers-of-hanoi

Can anybode help to understand the following?
I use algorithm "Tower og Hanoi" for programming crans movements. So have 3 slots (a, b, c). And move cargo from slot_a to slot_c, using slot_b as temporary.
I need to display what happens in each slot. (DIV's with ID = "port_a" etc. For this I use innerHTML.

Code:

```
const moveCranes = function(plate, slot_a, slot_b, slot_c) {
setTimeout(function() {
    if (plate > 0) {
        moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_a, slot_c, slot_b);
        port_a.innerHTML = "Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "..." + "</br>";
        port_b.innerHTML = "Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "..." + "</br>";
        port_c.innerHTML = "Moving plate " + plate + " from " + slot_a + " to " + slot_c + "..." + "</br>";
        moveCranes(plate - 1, slot_b, slot_a, slot_c);
    }
}, 2000);
};
    moveCranes(input.value,"slot_a","slot_b","slot_c");
```

But this code displays the same result for every step in each slot. The result mustn't be the same, because, for instance, when move plate from slot_a to slot_c, we have no movements in slot_b.

Please, give me hints!

Comment: You're setting exactly the same `innerHtml` for each of the 3 "slots", so it is hardly surprising that they are showing the same. I am familiar with the Tower of Hanoi puzzle and the algorithm to solve it, but I am not sure what you are aiming for this code to do.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond, it should be like a monitor. I want to display on screen (in 3 div's) the progress of doing this algorithm. So, into the first div I want to see the text "moving from a to c", in the second - nothing, in the third - "moving from a to c". And so on.

Comment: Ah, thanks - in that case you can just loop through the 3 divs, and if it matches `slot_a` then put the text in, otherwise remove the content. I still think this won't do exactly what you want - both your `setTimeout` callbacks inside the function will fire at the same time, with the result that you effectively won't see about half of the steps.

Comment: @  Robin Zigmond, thanks. Can you make changes to my code for example?

Comment: It's best I think to leave your question as it was, so everyone can see the code that wasn't working. I can put the changed code as an answer, if you like - but as I said, it won't fix the other issue, and I'm not too sure right now how to fix that one. (Using Promises would be one way, I'm sure, but I'm not particularly confident with them.)